# PHP não dá erro, mas também não cadastra corretamente

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um login, que se o usuário logar de outro celular, eu cadastro no meu BD o novo playerID (onesignal) dele.

O login funciona perfeitamente, mas não cadastra o novo playerID. E não da erro nenhum, simplesmente não cadastra.

Segue o código:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include 'conn-login.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){

if($_GET["acao"]=="login"){

    $emailL = $_GET['email'];
    $senhaL = $_GET['senha'];
    $playerID = $_GET['playerID'];
    $modelo = $_GET['modelo'];
    $sistema = $_GET['sistema'];        
    $cadastro = 'Facebook';
    $face_user_id = $_GET['face_id'];
    $datahora = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

    $sql = "SELECT id, nome, img_user, email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE (email =?) LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $emailL);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id_user, $nome, $img_user, $email_res, $senha);
    $stmt->store_result();

    if($stmt->num_rows <> 0){

        while ($stmt->fetch()){
            // checks if the user actually exists(true/false returned)
            if (password_verify($senhaL, $senha)){

                $var = Array(
                    'status' => 'OK',
                    'id' => $id_user,
                    'nome' => $nome,
                    'img_user' => $img_user,
                    'msg' => 'Logado com sucesso!'
                );

                $sql2 = "SELECT playerID FROM playersID WHERE (id_usuario =? AND playerID =?)";
                $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql2);
                $stmt2->bind_param('is', $id_user, $playerID);
                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->bind_result($playerID_res);
                $stmt2->store_result();

                if($stmt2->num_rows <= 0){

                    while ($stmt2->fetch()){

                        if($playerID != $playerID_res){

                            //INSERE O PLAYERID EM OUTRA TABELA
                            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO playersID (id_usuario, modelo, sistema, playerID, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                            $stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare($sql3);
                            $stmt3->bind_param('issss', $id_user, $modelo, $sistema, $playerID, $datahora);
                            $stmt3->execute();

                        } 

                        $stmt3->close(); 
                    }
                }

            } else {

                $var = Array(
                    'status' => 'ERRO',
                    'msg' => 'Usuário não cadastrado e/ou senha incorreta!'
                );
            }

            $stmt2->close(); 

        }

    $stmt->close();

    } else {

        $var = Array(
            'status' => 'ERRO',
            'msg' => 'Usuário não cadastrado e/ou senha incorreta!'
        );
    };

    echo json_encode($var);
}
}    

?>
```

O que não está cadastrando, é o SQL3. Alguém pode me dar uma luz do que estou fazendo de errado?

Aparentemente, não está passando dessa parte:

```
while ($stmt2->fetch()){
```

Obrigado!

Obs: está via GET, mas posteriormente mudarei pata POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema está aqui:

```
if($stmt2->num_rows <= 0){
   while ($stmt2->fetch()){
        if($playerID != $playerID_res){
```

Você está validando se existe algum player cadastro (aqui `if($stmt2->num_rows <= 0){)`.

Se não existir, você está executando um `while` nos resultados retornados (nesta linha `while ($stmt2->fetch()){`). Mas, não existe resultados retornados, pois, não existe o player. Ou seja, o `while` é exatamente o contrário da validação anterior.

Consequentemente, se não existe resultados, esta linha `if($playerID != $playerID_res){` sempre será diferente e não tem necessidade de existir. Pois, nunca irá retornar resultado algum.

Você deve remover o `while` e o `if` logo abaixo dele.

Mas, se o seguinte código`if($playerID != $playerID_res){` serve para validar se já existe um ID igual no banco, é melhor inserir uma `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` diretamente no banco de dados e tratar a exceção.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agora vou procurar como tratar a exceção!

Comment: Fiz de uma forma diferente: apenas validei se havia algum playerID no BD com aquele usuário e deu certo. Agora vou procurar sobre UNIQUE CONSTRAINT. Por acaso, teria alguma leitura para indicar?

Comment: Leia no seguinte link: [Indexes and Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-indexes-keys). Role um pouco a página e vai encontrar sobre `UNIQUE`